# Web push notifications stop working on Safari

Tags: firebase, push-notification, safari, progressive-web-apps, next.js13

I have implemented Web push notifications for a website built on NextJs 13 using Firebase and they are working perfectly on desktop Chrome, and Android Chrome. But on Safari macOS and IOS after adding the website to the home screen, the user initially starts receiving notifications after 3-4 notifications even if the user does nothing and just leaves the PWA open, the user stops receiving notifications foreground and background. On further debugging, I found out that the FCM device token gets changed.

I have no idea why it is changing automatically without doing anything It happens only for IOS.

IOS version 17.3 and 16.7, Firebase version 10.7.1

Notifications should work fine as they are working on other platforms.